# How to assign a specfic AWS cognito identity to user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I need to use IoT core MQTT but it need to attach IoT policy to the identity in order to access MQTT.

From aws doc, it can be done by calling the [AttachPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_AttachPolicy.html) API. But I  am struggling to use it successfully(see my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296215/how-to-attach-iot-policy-to-cognito-identity-using-api-gateway)). So I am trying alternative solution to assign user a specific identity and I attach the IoT policy through AWS CLI mannually.

I know that identity will be created when [GetId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) is called. But in my app I am using [Amplify.Auth](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js/) to sign up or sign in. I look through the doc and doesn't seem it mentioned when was GetId called.

Is it possible to assign a specfic identity to user when he/she is signed up or signed in?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% confident what you are looking for but, I have set up [this](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/pubsub/getting-started/q/platform/js/#step-1-create-iam-policies-for-aws-iot) before. can it give you a hint?

Comment: I am following this document too but I am stuck at step 2 of attaching iot policy to cognito identity ID. The document use CLI manually to do so. In my case, user log in by cognito will generate new identity id and I am finding method to attach iot policy automatically.

Comment: How about this Github examples part in [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cog-iot-policies.html)? I don't quite understand user login creates a new identity. Do you mean sign up?